# Simplify this property to be used in a predicate

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities, wcf-ria-services

I have many `Accounts`, each account can also have child accounts. So my way of knowing if an account is root is thanks to the value in the `ParentId` property.
So it turned out that my code has stuff like this in many places: `.Where(acc => acc.ParentId == 0)` so I thought about creating a property that looks like this:

```
public bool IsRootAccount
{
    return a.ParentId == 0;
}
```

It seems to work, it compiles, but when running I get the following exception:

`Load operation failed for query 'GetAccounts'. The specified type member 'IsRootAccount' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.`

Is there a simple way I can achieve what I want?

I also thought about creating something that would return an `Expression<Func<Account, bool>>` with no luck.

**Edit:** my attempt for the `IsRootAccount` property was in order to use something like this `.Where(acc => acc.IsRootAccount)`

Comment: The return type of `IsRootAccount` doesn't match the value that is returned (`bool` != lambda).

Comment: thanks, I fixed it... I copied it from a different property :)

Comment: Can you also show us the query you're trying to build that consumes this property?  I doubt you can do exactly what you want here, but we might be able to suggest some alternative solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple way to provide this functionality is using an extension method.

Try something like this:

```
public static class AccountEx
{
    public static IQueryable<Account> WhereIsRootAccount(
            this IQueryable<Account> source)
    {
        return source.Where(acc => acc.ParentId == 0);
    }
}
```

You then would replace every usage of `.Where(acc => acc.ParentId == 0)` with `.WhereIsRootAccount()`.

The advantage with this approach is that it works with EF and it provides a fluent way to query your root accounts. If you need to modify the definition of a root account you also only have one place to make the change. And it doesn't pollute your `Account` class with unnecessary code.

I hope this helps.

---

Based on your comment, try this:

```
public static class AccountEx
{
    public static EntityQuery<Account> WhereIsRootAccount(
            this EntityQuery<Account> source)
    {
        return source.Where(acc => acc.ParentId == 0);
    }
}
```

Since `Where` is supported by `EntityQuery<>` then it should still work fine.

Comment: I love the idea... will give it a try

Comment: It does help, thanks... but it can't be used from the Silverlight client, right? is there a way of doing that on the client side?

Comment: @sebastian - I'm not totally up on Silverlight - can you tell me why you don't think this'll work from Silverlight?

Comment: because the RIA service that expose my data exposes my return values as `EntityQuery<Account>` which is exclusively from the Silverlight framework...  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.domainservices.client.entityquery(v=vs.91).aspx

Comment: @sebastian - Please see my modified answer.

Comment: yes, that's what I thought and it works but I must have two identical methods, one for the server side and the later for the client side... I guess that's the only way

Answer (score 0):

Here's something I found but I would like to see if there's anything better to do.
I understand EF does not know how to transform my predicate to SQL because of my property.
So I can't do this:

```
Context.Load(Context.GetAccountsQuery().Where(acc => acc.IsRootAccount), ParentAccountsArrived, null);
```

but I do can filter with my property once the results are back from the server:

```
public void LoadParentAccounts()
{
    Context.Load(Context.GetAccountsQuery(), ParentAccountsArrived, null);  
}
void ParentAccountsArrived(LoadOperation<Account> lo)
{
    foreach (var account in lo.Entities.Where(acc => acc.IsRootAccount))
    {
        ParentAccounts.Add(account.Name);
    }
}
```

Is this the way to go? Is there a performance issue with this change?

Comment: is a method of a RIA service which returns an `IQueryable<Account>`